# process tar files

Tags: google-bigquery

I am not able to process any tar files.

```
Errors:
Line:1 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with: <Master.c>
Line:2 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.
Input contained no data
```

Job ID: cdrFinal20130123193311freeswitch8

If I upload uncompressed files, there is no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tar is not a compression format - it is an archival format. BigQuery currently supports loading of files compressed using the gzip algorithm.

More here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/ingestioncookbook#compressedversusuncompressed

Comment: I used tar's compression switch -z and I thought big query will handle it. Is it possible to support compressed tar files? I get a lot of such files from client and I can not ask them to change their script.

Comment: tar -z will archive your files in a format unique to tar, and then compress the resulting archive with gzip.  When BigQuery decompresses your gzipped file, the output will be a tar archive, which BigQuery doesn't understand.

If your CSV files all have the same schema and are to be imported at the same time, you could produce a single uploadable file by concatentating them and then compressing them (e.g., "cat 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv | gzip - > out.csv.gz").

Comment: Can you please add this as a feature request? (support for tar -z format)

Comment: Hi there - you can now file your own BigQuery feature requests and issue reports on our new public issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list